# SED Delete line Previous the Match and Proceeding Line

Tags: sed

I have a file that has text like this:

```
Begin  
Certificate  
End  

Begin  
PKIValue1  
End  

Begin  
PKIValue2  
End  

Begin  
Certificate  
End
```

I want to remove the three lines associated with `Certificate` but keep the remaining `Begin` and `End` for the `PKIValues`.

I have been testing with this SED line:

```
sed -n -e '/Certificate/{x;1!p;g;$!N;p;D;}' -e h $cert_file>PKI.txt
```

That line does the opposite of what I want.  It keeps only the `Certificate` value and the associated `Begin` and `End`.  How can I delete the `certificate` but keep the other lines for `PKIValues`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
$ sed -n -e '/Begin/{N;N;N;/Certificate/!p;}' file
Begin
PKIValue1
End

Begin
PKIValue2
End
```

#### How it works

```
`/Begin/{N;N;N;/Certificate/!p;}`
```

Every time there is a `Begin` line, we gather it and the next three lines, `N;N;N;`, into the pattern space.  If the pattern space now contains `Certificate`, we skip this grouping.  If it doesn't, we print it.

Comment: I like your suggestion.  On my initial tests though it keeps telling me   sed: command garbled: /Begin/{N;N;N;/Certificate/!p}

Comment: @user3735276 It works for me under GNU `sed`.  I suspect that you are using BSD.  Try adding another semicolon: `sed -n -e '/Begin/{N;N;N;/Certificate/!p;}' file`

Comment: That worked like a champ.  Thanks a lot.  I got all wrapped up in trying to use the hold space and swap it out based on the SED oneliners examples.  I like your solution much better and it is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: @user3735276 Excellent.  I have added that semicolon into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This small `gnu awk` should do:

```
awk '!/Certificate/' RS= ORS="\n\n" file
Begin
PKIValue1
End

Begin
PKIValue2
End
```

Setting `RS` record selector to nothing makes it work in block mode (gnu function)
`!/Certificate/'` this just remove blocks with `Certificate`

This works fine if there are various number of lines in the block.